# Pythagorean trigonometric identity rule broken in VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, trigonometry, math.h

After upgrading to Visual Studio 2013 I noticed that some basic math functions became working differently, for example sin() from `<cmath>` or `<math.h>`. That might be a good changes, but some tests showed of one of the main mathematical rule is broken. Here is the test function:

```
void Test()
{
  double d_angle = M_PI_2 / 2;

  auto sin_val = sin(d_angle);
  auto cos_val = cos(d_angle);
  auto sum_of_squares = sin_val*sin_val + cos_val*cos_val;

  Assert::AreEqual(1.0, sum_of_squares, 1e-16);
}
```

This test fails with VS2013, but passes with VS2012.

What can be done to handle this situation and have result of VS2012?

Comment: "1e-16". May I ask which fundamental law of nature governs this particular constant?

Comment: @n.m. Probably this one: ["This gives 15–17 significant decimal digits precision.“](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: What happens if you replace `auto` with `double` and/or reduce the required precision to `1e-15`?

Comment: @Sleafar changing precision will make the test pass of course

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is that floating point math is not real math (or at least not math on the set of real numbers).  An IEEE 754 double precision floating-point number has a 53-bit mantissa.  You `Assert::AreEqual` specifies that the mantissa of `sum_of_squares` should be a 1 bit, followed by 52 zero bits ±1e-16.

An error in the least significant bit would be 1 ± 2<sup>-52</sup> = 1 ± 2.220446e-16, so if the least significant bit rounds differently, your `Assert::AreEqual` will fail.  Essentially, you are saying that the answer must be calculated with 0 error.

Apparently, VS2012 got the answer exactly correct and now VS2013 does not.  There are several possible reasons this might be:

1. VS2013 is not doing IEEE 754 compliant math.  Math bugs have happened in the past, but are rare.  It is unlikely to be a compiler or math library bug if the result you get is off by less than one bit in the least significant position.
2. The VS2013 compiler reorders floating-point operations, which changes how partial results get rounded.  Compilers are not supposed to reorder floating-point operations if the result would change, but most have optimization flags that allow re-ordering that is allowed by math on real numbers when it will improve performance (e.g., -ffast-math in gcc).  This is probably not the issue unless you have been experimenting with compiler options.
3. The VS2013 compiler optimizer decides differently what mix of x87 and SSE/SSE2 instructions to use, or it changes how it does register allocation.  The x87 FPU has a 80-bit floating point registers, whereas SSE2 has 64-bit floating point registers.  If the compiler keeps a computation in the x87 floating point registers and only stores the final result, that result might get rounded differently than a result computed with SSE2, due to the longer mantissa used for intermediate values.
4. The compiler forces an intermediate result into memory due to register pressure.  As a result one or more intermediate values are being truncated to a 64-bit float.  With such a short program, that is unlikely.

If you bump the `delta` parameter to `Assert::AreEqual` up to 2.23e-16 and it passes, then the difference is that the least significant bit is rounded.

According to the [VS2013 documentation for the `/arch` compiler option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd(v=vs.120).aspx):

> The optimizer chooses when and how to use the SSE and SSE2 instructions when /arch is specified. It uses SSE and SSE2 instructions for some scalar floating-point computations when it determines that it is faster to use the SSE/SSE2 instructions and registers instead of the x87 floating-point register stack. As a result, your code may actually use a mixture of both x87 and SSE/SSE2 for floating-point computations. Also, with /arch:SSE2, SSE2 instructions can be used for some 64-bit integer operations.

and

> Because the x86 compiler generates code that uses SSE2 instructions by default, you must specify /arch:IA32 to disable generation of SSE and SSE2 instructions for x86 processors.

The VS2012 documentation says nearly the same thing.  Both are vague about precisely when the compiler will choose x87 or SSE/SSE2.

Looking at the disassembly will tell you which instructions the compiler is using, and whether the result gets written out to memory.

Comment: This is a great post of explanation, thank you. But having checked all the settings be the same in VS2012 and VS2013 I still have different results. It seems that sin() has been rewritten or something. And I still need a workaround.

Comment: How big is the difference between VS2012 and VS2013?  If it is less than 2.23e-16, then the difference is what you can expect to see between different compilers, platforms, etc. and you probably just have to live with it.  Did you look at the disassembly to see if both compilers are generating the same instructions?

Comment: the diff is 2e-16. Disassembly instructions are different at least for sin(). And that is the whole problem. The function sin() gives different result in comparison between 2013vs2012. Change is about 1.1e-15 (not 16), what actually breaks old behavior.